# Overcoming a boost converters soft start function

Tags: dc-dc-converter, boost

I am using a [TPS61235p](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61235p.pdf) to boost a 3.7V 18650 battery to 5.1v with a pure-resitive load of 2Ω.  I expect it to draw 2.5A, but upon pulling the enable pin high the output current is limited to about ~1.75A due to the soft-start functionality described on [page 10 of the datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61235p.pdf).

I have confirmed this by increasing the load resistance higher than the Fig 8 Minimum Load Resistance at Startup, and then bypassing my increased resistance, confirming I now have the proper output.  The booster never comes out of soft-start unless the load resistance is increased first, then reduced after the booster started switching.

The enable pin is controlled by an Arduino, so now I'm wondering how do I decrease the load resistance once I've enabled the booster.

My first thought was to put a resistor in-line like I am now, and then use a N-channel MOSFET to bypass the resistor after the booster has started.  But is there a more robust / effecient way to do this?

Forgive my cramped circuit, I'm still learning.

- SYS is VCC, battery voltage unless its being charged
- VOUT goes
  straight to the load
- EN and INACT go to the Arduino

[image: Boost circuit]

Comment: Soft start is basically always desirable. Why exactly is it a problem?

Comment: When using such a low resistance load, the boost converter never comes out of soft-start.  Its described on the top of page 11, and they recommend applying a small load or no load at all until the booster starts up.

I just don't know the best way to do that yet.

Comment: The problem with a PFET is that Vout is 0V to start and it only stays off as long as Vout < Vgsth! Also want to make sure the PFET can handle the power dissipation during soft-start. What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Costs a GPIO pin, but simple.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fF8P5i.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Make sure the MOSFET you choose is rated for the 2.5A continuous,has a logic level gate and a low Rds on. Pull the gate low after Vout stabilizes. If that part had a power good output, you could even tie the power good signal to the gate.